# Run code, e.g. login, depending on which test suite is executed

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

**TL;DR:** I would like to run code before a test suite that depends on which test suite is going to be run, e.g. login as a certain user.

---

Part of my `wdio.conf.js` looks something like this:

```
exports.config = {
    specs: [
        './spec/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    suites: {
        allExceptAandB: [
            './spec/**/!(A|B).spec.js'
        ],
        A: [
            './spec/A.spec.js'
        ],
        B: [
            './spec/B.spec.js'
        ]
    },
    [...]
}
```

When running tests using the command line argument `--suite A` only the `A.spec.js` will be run, so it's as one (or at least I) would expect.

What I would now like to do is to run some code before the actual tests depending on which suite I'm running, e.g. `login(usernameA, passwordA)` or `login(usernameB, passwordB)`.

If I use

```
before: function(capabilities, specs) {
    login(username, password)
}
```

in my `wdio.conf.js`, this part seems to be executed before every single spec, and using

```
beforeSuite: function(suite) {
    console.log(suite)
}
```

showed me that it was also executed before every spec, and printed

```
{ type: 'beforeSuite',
  title: '<2nd level describe title>',
  fullName: '<top level describe title> <2nd level describe title>',
  file: 'pathTo/spec/some.spec.js' }
```

I would expect

- `before` to be run before any test suite is started
- `beforeSuite` to be run before every suite, and that I would have some way of accessing the name of the suite to be executed, so I can adapt e.g. login parameters

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Lacking other solutions, I came up with a “dirty hack” in my `wdio.conf.js` that reads the command line arguments and thus determines which suite is being run

```
before: function (capabilities, suite, specs) {
    let suiteNameCliParamIndex = process.argv.indexOf("--suite") + 1
    let suiteName = process.argv[suiteNameCliParamIndex]
    if(suiteName === 'thisSuite') {
        doThisStuff()
    } else {
        doOtherStuff()
    }
}
```